# How to run java exec from NodeJs and get return value

Tags: java, node.js

I use NodeJs and I want to exec java program and catch the return value from the program - How can I do that?

For example: in NodeJs I got file name as param --> I pass the file name to the java exec program that analyze the file, extract the text and return it.

There is an option to catch the text that the java program return?

Comment: take a look at [Child process API](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me when I need execute shell commands using nodejs:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");

exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

**stdout** variable will have the returned text of command

You just change **ls -la** to **java -version** or any other java commands